# How do I write Console.Writeline(" \|\/ \| /"); and ignore "Unrecognized escape sequence" error?

Tags: c#, console-application, console.writeline

For example I don't want this line of code: `Console.Writeline(" \|\/ \| /");` to interfere with the program, because at the moment I'm getting the error Unrecognized escape sequence but I don't want to use an escape sequence, I just want those characters themselves to appear on the console.
Is there any way of doing this? Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Use a literal, `Console.Writeline(@"\|/\ \| ?");`.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds to me like you want a *verbatim string literal*, which doesn't treat backslash as an escape character, and also allows for multi-line literals:

```
Console.Writeline(@" \|\/ \| /");
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) or [the "literals" section of my article on strings](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx#literals) for more details. Note that you *will* still need a bit of work for double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.Writeline(@" \|/ \| /");
```

[MSDN string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Console.Writeline(@" \|/ \| /");
```

The `@` character tells the compiler to not process escape sequences.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as `Console.WriteLine(@" \|/ \| /")`.  The `@` symbol tells visual studio to use the string exactly as written.

Alternatively, replace each `\` with `\\`, which is the escape sequence which displays a `\`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@` called [`verbatim string literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
Console.Writeline(@" \|/ \| /");
```

> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing
>   double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim
>   string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted
>   verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In
>   particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want those characters themselves to appear on the console.

Then you either have to use an escape sequence, or a [*verbatim string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
Console.Writeline(@" \|/ \| /");
```

Answer (score 0):

prefix the string with an "@" like

```
@" \|/ \| /"
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternately, you could actually use (and understand) the escape sequences correctly. To use `\` in your strings, you need to escape them. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx for reference

So, your actual command would be

```
// Escaped characters make this show up as "\|/ \| /"
Console.Writeline(" \\|/ \\| /");
```

But the output would be `\|/ \| /`